# Unhandled ObjectDisposedException C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, razor, blazor

I'm programming a wiki with razor pages in the blazor framework.

Everything was going fine, then I got this error message:

> fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
> An error occurred using the connection to database 'aspnet-InternesWiki-8BAA8CA5-BC83-4528-BE5F-4E702A44D17F' on server '(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB'.
> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher[8]
> Failed to invoke hub method 'ConnectCircuit'.
> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost.SetCircuitUser(ClaimsPrincipal user)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ComponentHub.ConnectCircuit(String circuitIdSecret)
> at lambda_method11(Closure , Object )
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher`1.ExecuteMethod(ObjectMethodExecutor methodExecutor, Hub hub, Object[] arguments) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher`1.g__ExecuteInvocation|16_0(DefaultHubDispatcher`1 dispatcher, ObjectMethodExecutor methodExecutor, THub hub, Object[] arguments, AsyncServiceScope scope, IHubActivator`1 hubActivator, HubConnectionContext connection, HubMethodInvocationMessage hubMethodInvocationMessage, Boolean isStreamCall)

This is where the error occurs:

```cs
public async Task<bool> Insertiket(Eintrage eintag)
        {
            _context.Eintrage.Add(eintag);
            _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return true;
        }
```

`SaveChangesAsync()` It is no longer executed.

Hopefully you can help me, I don't know what to do.

Many thanks in advance

all project files:

https://anonfiles.com/j1c4Fet1y1/InternesWiki_7z

Comment: Sounds like something has been disposed that should not have been.

Comment: @CodeStranger Yes, I do not dispose of it and I do not find anything in the code that would dispose of it.

Comment: The warning that this code generates is telling you exactly what is wrong with it.

Comment: fyi - `return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();`

Comment: You forgot to `await` the call to `SaveChangesAsync`, it's likely the context is disposed by DI before that is completing.

Comment: @RandRandom You can't return there since SaveChangesAsync returns a `Task<int>`

Comment: @DavidG - been a while since my last EF days, so success is indicated with > 0? or would you need to try/catch it ?

Comment: @RandRandom The number is the number of records updated.  Whether you define "successful" as that number being more than 0 will depend on your business logic (but that will often be the case).  But in some cases updating nothing will still be successful, and in other cases more than one record would need to be updated for it to be "successful".

Answer (score 2):

Reading the exception carefully, we see this:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher[8] Failed to invoke hub method 'ConnectCircuit'. System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.

It's not a database issue, it's a SignalR one. By reading the SignalR Hubs API Guide at the [Hub Object Lifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#hub-object-lifetime) section we learn this:

> Because instances of the Hub class are transient, you can't use them to maintain state from one method call to the next. Each time the server receives a method call from a client, a new instance of your Hub class processes the message

Now, I don't have the full picture of your architecture, my guess is that you have multiple method calls with that db write operation at the end, when the original Hub class generated at the first method call had already been disposed.